# UINavigationBar Appears Under UIStatusBar

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

`UINavigationBar` Appears Under `UIStatusBar` in iOS 6(It runs properly in iOS 7), I am using storyboard with Xocde 5,

[image]:
Here is my code snippet,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = NO;

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7) //iOS 6
    {
        [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TabImg.png"]];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.7 green:.2 blue:.1 alpha:1.0]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Code on HomePage,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

        CRViewController *Obj=[[CRViewController alloc] init];
        [self.tabBarController presentViewController:Obj animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

When i run my app after `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method `viewDidLoad` gets fired and this calls `CRViewController` class.

Code on `CRViewController`,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;

     ...
     ...
     ...

}



- (IBAction)SkipClick:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = NO;
}
```

**Where i am doing mistake ??**

***Thanks in advance.***

Comment: Hi, i am facing same issue in my app,set time delay after present your view controller

Comment: try this - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

      [self performSelector:@selector(presentListView) withObject:self afterDelay:0.5];

}

-(void)presentListView
{
 CRViewController *Obj=[[CRViewController alloc] init];
        [self.tabBarController presentViewController:Obj animated:YES completion:nil];
}

Answer (score 0):

```
Navigation is showing in ios 7 than you have check this it will work


NSString *version = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
int ver = [version intValue];
if (ver > 7)
{
}
else
{
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

}

self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;   is not working in ios 7  it shows the black screen. Than you can hide it

-(void)hideTabBar

{

UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;

UIView *parent = tabBar.superview; // UILayoutContainerView

UIView *content = [parent.subviews objectAtIndex:0];  // UITransitionView

UIView *window = parent.superview;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5

animations:^
{

CGRect tabFrame = tabBar.frame;

tabFrame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(window.bounds);

tabBar.frame = tabFrame;
                     content.frame = window.bounds;

}];

}